# Should a job listing site use structured data in a country which Google Jobs doesn't cover?

Tags: seo, google-search, structured-data, google-jobs

Firstly, I suspect ‘Google for Jobs’ may be the incorrect term, is it called 'Google Jobs' now?

I'm in Europe, Ireland to be precise. We don't have ‘Google for Jobs’ here, and I read that we may not for some time, if at all, if some lobby groups have their way.

I run a job board site - 95% of the jobs are in Europe and about 80% of our job seekers are there too.

Is there any point in us marking up with JSON-LD or HTML Microdata?

If the answer is Yes, I have a follow up question.

Do you just put it on the job detail page, or what about the category listing page where you have multiple job titles linking to the detail pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided a substantial proportion of your European customers are located in [supported European countries](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#region-availability), and you're reasonably sure that it will drive enough extra revenue to justify the costs, yes.

I strongly recommend opting for JSON-LD, rather than microdata. In either case it lives on the job detail pages, not the category pages. You'll find implementation details on the page linked above.

Comment: Thank you. The UK support might justify it. Is there any options to help the category pages?

Comment: You're welcome, and no — all available structured data is documented in the Google documentation I've linked to.